# SVG With two colors in WP Elementor as Logo

Tags: css, wordpress, svg, elementor, adobe-illustrator

i have the following problem:

I want to use a SVG file as logo and i want to adjust the logo height/width with CSS/Elementor interface to make it responsive. It works when i remove the inline styles with a text editor, but then the whole logo is black. The logo got 2 colors (red/white).

Is it possible to change the .svg Code, that you can still adjust the size of the logo but not the colors when working with wordpress elementor?

```css
body {
  background-color: linen;
}
```

```html
<svg id="Ebene_1" data-name="Ebene 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="745.86" height="256.4" viewBox="0 0 745.86 256.4"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#fff;}.cls-2{fill:#931825;}</style></defs><path class="cls-1" d="M134.33,153.41h20.56a34.26,34.26,0,0,0,15.56-3.26,23,23,0,0,0,9.93-9.31,28.58,28.58,0,0,0,3.45-14.43v-7.75a25.68,25.68,0,0,0-2.37-11.25,20.82,20.82,0,0,0-6.82-8.15,23.65,23.65,0,0,0-10.67-4,24,24,0,0,0,10-4.08,19.79,19.79,0,0,0,6.24-7.52,23.32,23.32,0,0,0,2.18-10.2V67.3A29.08,29.08,0,0,0,179,52.94a22,22,0,0,0-9.85-9.15q-6.53-3.18-15.91-3.18h-36.6v112.8Zm30.18-43.64a17,17,0,0,1,1.48,7.41v7.61q0,5.65-3.53,8.8t-10.59,3.14H134.33v-33.2h18.23a16,16,0,0,1,7.41,1.59,10,10,0,0,1,4.54,4.65ZM151.94,57.29q6.13,0,9.39,2.91c2.17,1.94,3.26,4.74,3.26,8.42v5.89q0,6.06-3.1,9.23t-9.08,3.19H134.33V57.29Z" transform="translate(-48.02 -39.44)"/><path class="cls-1" d="M244.22,102.64a25.33,25.33,0,0,0,10.59-10.32,32.23,32.23,0,0,0,3.73-15.87V69.86a31.44,31.44,0,0,0-3.73-15.64,25,25,0,0,0-10.55-10.16,34.68,34.68,0,0,0-16.14-3.53H191V153.41h17.69V106.24h13.86l19.58,47.17h20.32l-21.64-49.28A27.93,27.93,0,0,0,244.22,102.64ZM208.73,57.52h19.78a12,12,0,0,1,6.25,1.59,10.35,10.35,0,0,1,4.07,4.54,15.75,15.75,0,0,1,1.4,6.83v6.13a16.1,16.1,0,0,1-1.48,6.79,9.92,9.92,0,0,1-4.07,4.34,12.21,12.21,0,0,1-6.17,1.51H208.73Z" transform="translate(-48.02 -39.44)"/><path class="cls-1" d="M314.06,40.61h-13.5l-34.45,112.8h18.7l5.77-21.25H324l5.77,21.25H348.5ZM295.13,115.4l12.18-44.84,12.17,44.84Z" transform="translate(-48.02 -39.44)"/><polygon class="cls-1" points="321.47 36.79 357.86 113.9 375.16 113.9 375.16 1.17 358.24 1.17 358.24 80.42 321.63 1.17 304.56 1.17 304.56 113.9 321.47 113.9 321.47 36.79"/><path class="cls-1" d="M497.08,138.4a35.88,35.88,0,0,0,4-17.42V73q0-10.32-4-17.57a26.47,26.47,0,0,0-11.71-11.06q-7.68-3.79-18.47-3.8H434v112.8h32.81q11,0,18.62-3.84A26.39,26.39,0,0,0,497.08,138.4Zm-14.16-17.57q0,7.53-4.23,11.56t-12,4h-15V57.6h15q7.76,0,12,4t4.23,11.56Z" transform="translate(-48.02 -39.44)"/><path class="cls-1" d="M538.82,122.69q0,7-3.26,10.75t-9.31,3.76a15.26,15.26,0,0,1-7.25-1.79,16.5,16.5,0,0,1-5.7-5l-13.58,11a28.62,28.62,0,0,0,11.13,9.69,34,34,0,0,0,15.32,3.42,35.05,35.05,0,0,0,16.53-3.65,24.35,24.35,0,0,0,10.51-10.67,36.26,36.26,0,0,0,3.61-16.87V40.61h-18Z" transform="translate(-48.02 -39.44)"/><path class="cls-1" d="M583,150.5q7.49,4.08,18,4.08t18-4.08a27.11,27.11,0,0,0,11.44-11.87q4-7.78,4-18.73V40.61H616.75v79.75q0,8-4.07,12.34t-11.6,4.3q-7.46,0-11.48-4.34t-4-12.34V40.61H567.8V119.9q0,10.93,3.88,18.73A26.63,26.63,0,0,0,583,150.5Z" transform="translate(-48.02 -39.44)"/><polygon class="cls-1" points="649.61 80.42 612.99 1.17 595.93 1.17 595.93 113.9 612.84 113.9 612.84 36.79 649.22 113.9 666.52 113.9 666.52 1.17 649.61 1.17 649.61 80.42"/><path class="cls-1" d="M760.36,92.05v17h15.51v10.47a21,21,0,0,1-1.94,9.35,13.78,13.78,0,0,1-5.51,6,16.51,16.51,0,0,1-8.45,2.06,18.11,18.11,0,0,1-8.61-1.94,13.59,13.59,0,0,1-5.63-5.51,17,17,0,0,1-2-8.38v-46a22.2,22.2,0,0,1,1.9-9.47,14.14,14.14,0,0,1,5.47-6.21,15.81,15.81,0,0,1,8.38-2.17,14,14,0,0,1,7.26,1.86,13.4,13.4,0,0,1,5,5.55,24.65,24.65,0,0,1,2.37,9.19h18.77Q792.1,62.57,788,54.88A27.48,27.48,0,0,0,776.7,43.32q-7.17-3.87-17.26-3.87a36,36,0,0,0-18,4.3,29.21,29.21,0,0,0-11.79,12.38,40.83,40.83,0,0,0-4.15,18.93V121a36.74,36.74,0,0,0,4.19,17.89,28.09,28.09,0,0,0,12,11.67,39.16,39.16,0,0,0,18.2,4,36,36,0,0,0,18-4.31A29.23,29.23,0,0,0,789.72,138a40.15,40.15,0,0,0,4.15-18.77V92.05Z" transform="translate(-48.02 -39.44)"/><path class="cls-1" d="M142.94,181.84,109.12,294.65h14.43l7.14-26.07h38l7.14,26.07h14.43L156.44,181.84Zm-8.88,74.4,15.63-57.1,15.64,57.1Z" transform="translate(-48.02 -39.44)"/><path class="cls-1" d="M224.83,247.09h19.79v13.34a29.93,29.93,0,0,1-2.33,12.46,16.56,16.56,0,0,1-6.71,7.64,21.09,21.09,0,0,1-10.75,2.56,23.3,23.3,0,0,1-11.09-2.45,16.22,16.22,0,0,1-7-7.1,24.65,24.65,0,0,1-2.36-11.24V216.21a29.49,29.49,0,0,1,2.33-12.33,17,17,0,0,1,6.78-7.8,20.63,20.63,0,0,1,10.83-2.68,17.81,17.81,0,0,1,9.27,2.33,16.83,16.83,0,0,1,6.32,7,30.32,30.32,0,0,1,3,11.48h14.27q-.76-11-4.77-18.5a26.59,26.59,0,0,0-11-11.25q-7-3.77-17-3.76-10.56,0-18,4.15A27,27,0,0,0,195,197q-3.87,8-3.88,19.24V262.3q0,10.62,3.92,18.19a25.91,25.91,0,0,0,11.52,11.44q7.6,3.88,18.31,3.88t18-4.15a27,27,0,0,0,11.37-12.14q3.87-8,3.88-19.24v-25.6H224.83Z" transform="translate(-48.02 -39.44)"/><polygon class="cls-1" points="228.52 142.4 220.84 142.4 220.84 255.21 228.52 255.21 234.11 255.21 281.28 255.21 281.28 242.72 234.11 242.72 234.11 205.4 275.07 205.4 275.07 192.99 234.11 192.99 234.11 154.89 281.28 154.89 281.28 142.4 234.11 142.4 228.52 142.4"/><polygon class="cls-1" points="346.41 228.87 302.26 142.4 290.08 142.4 290.08 255.13 303.04 255.13 303.04 169.84 347.03 255.13 359.44 255.13 359.44 142.4 346.41 142.4 346.41 228.87"/><polygon class="cls-1" points="367.47 154.89 394.39 154.89 394.39 255.21 407.66 255.21 407.66 154.89 434.66 154.89 434.66 142.4 367.47 142.4 367.47 154.89"/><path class="cls-1" d="M542.55,262.3q0,10.15-4.93,15.36t-14.55,5.19q-9.54,0-14.43-5.19t-4.89-15.36V181.84H490.49v80q0,11.1,3.68,18.7A24.89,24.89,0,0,0,505.11,292q7.26,3.84,18,3.84t18-3.88a25.22,25.22,0,0,0,11-11.44q3.72-7.56,3.72-18.66v-80H542.55Z" transform="translate(-48.02 -39.44)"/><path class="cls-1" d="M618.5,243.37a25.1,25.1,0,0,0,10.59-10.25,31.68,31.68,0,0,0,3.72-15.67v-6.59a31.43,31.43,0,0,0-3.68-15.52,24.48,24.48,0,0,0-10.59-10.08,35.74,35.74,0,0,0-16.3-3.49H566.56V294.65h13.26V246.93h22.43l19.23,47.72h15.29l-21.36-49.92A31.47,31.47,0,0,0,618.5,243.37Zm-38.68-49.11H603.1a17.21,17.21,0,0,1,8.69,2.09,14,14,0,0,1,5.62,6.05,20.46,20.46,0,0,1,2,9.23v5.82a20.67,20.67,0,0,1-2,9.08,13.36,13.36,0,0,1-5.62,5.9,17.81,17.81,0,0,1-8.65,2H579.82Z" transform="translate(-48.02 -39.44)"/><path class="cls-1" d="M673.28,196a10.41,10.41,0,0,0,.05-13.9c-1.76-1.74-4.29-2.62-7.6-2.62H655V207.8h5.86v-9.14h4.85l4.29,9.09h6.5l-5.21-10.31A8.29,8.29,0,0,0,673.28,196Zm-12.41-11.38h5a4.18,4.18,0,0,1,3.06,1.14,4.3,4.3,0,0,1,1.16,3.27,4.6,4.6,0,0,1-1.16,3.36,4.1,4.1,0,0,1-3.06,1.18h-5Z" transform="translate(-48.02 -39.44)"/><path class="cls-1" d="M678.51,168.64a33.47,33.47,0,0,0-27.3,0,19.7,19.7,0,0,0-8.61,8.5,28.39,28.39,0,0,0-3,13.45v6.78a27.8,27.8,0,0,0,3,13.24,19.47,19.47,0,0,0,8.64,8.39,33.89,33.89,0,0,0,27.24,0,19.62,19.62,0,0,0,8.64-8.39,27.54,27.54,0,0,0,3-13.24v-6.78a28.39,28.39,0,0,0-3-13.45A19.91,19.91,0,0,0,678.51,168.64Zm5.68,28.73a20.79,20.79,0,0,1-2.27,10,15,15,0,0,1-6.64,6.36,26,26,0,0,1-20.86,0,15,15,0,0,1-6.59-6.36,20.68,20.68,0,0,1-2.28-10v-6.78a22.4,22.4,0,0,1,2.28-10.52,15.25,15.25,0,0,1,6.59-6.61,25.16,25.16,0,0,1,20.9,0,15.43,15.43,0,0,1,6.6,6.61,22.52,22.52,0,0,1,2.27,10.52Z" transform="translate(-48.02 -39.44)"/><rect class="cls-2" width="23.35" height="256.37"/></svg>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "when i remove the inline styles" please?  Your question isn't particularly clear.  Please add some details.

Comment: Generally, to make your SVG responsive, you would need to either (a) remove the `width` and `height` attributes, or (b) set them both to `"100%"`.   But doing that should not make your SVG all black.

Comment: Everything turns black when you **remove** those class style settings.. because in SVG ``undefined`` defaults to black.